# Do these two commutative diagrams represent the same homomorphism?

Tags: abstract-algebra, logic

Consider the two many-sorted algebras $\mathtt{A}$, $\mathtt{B}$ and the homomorphism $h:\mid \mathtt{A}\mid  \to \mid \mathtt{B}\mid$ below. Do the commutative diagrams in Figure 1 and Figure 2 both adequately represent $h$? Can $h_2$ be dropped from Figure 1 to give Figure 2? As far as I know identity and composition are not labelled on commutative diagrams.

$\mathtt{A}$, $\mathtt{B}$ and $h$ are based on this [paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/243766148_Approaching_the_Issue_of_Information_Loss_in_Geographic_Data_Transfers).

In algebra  $\mathtt{A}$ a point is represented by a triple consisting of a name and integer coordinates. Points are considered equal if they have the same name.

\begin{aligned}
& \mathtt{Point_A} = \{ \langle name,x,y \rangle \mid name \in \mathtt{String}, x,y \in \mathbb{Z}  \} \\
& \mathtt{equal_A}  : \mathtt{Point_A} \times \mathtt{Point_A} \to \mathbb{B}\\
& \mathtt{equal_A}(\langle  name_1,x_1,y_1 \rangle , \langle  name_2,x_2,y_2 \rangle) \triangleq  (name_1 =_{\mathtt{String}} name_2)
\end{aligned}

Algebra $\mathtt{B}$ represents a point as a coordinate 2-tuple with point equality based the integer  value of each coordinate component.

\begin{aligned}
& \mathtt{Point_B} =\{ \langle x,y\rangle \mid x,y \in \mathbb{Z}\} \\
& \mathtt{equal_B}  : \mathtt{Point_B} \times \mathtt{Point_B} \to \mathbb{B}\\
&\mathtt{equal_B}(\langle x_1,y_1 \rangle ,\langle x_2,y_2 \rangle ) \triangleq  ((x_1 =_\mathbb{Z} x_2) \land (y_1 =_\mathbb{Z} y_2))
\end{aligned}

The homomorphism $h:\mid \mathtt{A}\mid  \to \mid \mathtt{B}\mid$ is defined as follows:
\begin{aligned}
 & h_1 : \mathtt{Point_A}  \to \mathtt{Point_B}\\
 & h_1(\langle name,x,y \rangle) = \langle x,y \rangle \\
 & h_2 : \mathbb{B} \to \mathbb{B}\\
 & h_2(x) = x\\
\end{aligned}
Where $h_1$ forgets the name and $h_2$ is an identity mapping.

The commutative diagram in Figure 1 represents homomorphism: $h_2(\mathtt{equal_A}(a,b)) =  \mathtt{equal_B}(h_1(a), h_1(b))$?

[image]

The commutative diagram in Figure 2 represents homomorphism: $\mathtt{equal_A}(a,b) =\mathtt{equal_B}(h_1(a), h_1(b))$.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your definition of $h_2$ as the identity on $\mathbb{B}$, Figure 1 and 2 are equivalent, i.e. $h_2$ can be dropped from Figure 1 to give Figure 2, which has the same meaning as Figure 1.

The problem is that the diagrams in Figure 1 and 2 do not commute! Take in $|\mathtt{A}|$
\begin{align}
a_1 &= \langle \text{Rome}, 0, 1 \rangle & a_2 &= \langle \text{Rome}, 0, 2 \rangle
\end{align}
Then, $\mathtt{equal_A}(a_1, a_2)$ is true because $\text{Rome} =_\mathtt{String} \text{Rome}$, but $h_1(a_1) = \langle 0,1 \rangle$ and $h_1(a_2) = \langle 0, 2\rangle$, hence $\mathtt{equal_B}(h_1(a_1), h_1(a_2)) = \mathtt{equal_B}(\langle 0,1\rangle, \langle 0 , 2\rangle)$ is false because $1 \neq_\mathbb{Z} 2$.

Of course, the two diagrams commute if you assume that there are no different places with the same name.

Comment: In the [paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/243766148_Approaching_the_Issue_of_Information_Loss_in_Geographic_Data_Transfers)  non-commutativity is taken as an _information loss_.  So, places with the same name in different locations would indeed be a problem.